# How to remove/cut off a steel post in concrete

Tags: concrete, steel, gate-post, angle-grinder

As part of some renovation work, I am taking apart a small enclosure on my driveway. Having removed the "walls", I'm left with seven (what look like) galvanised steel posts, embedded in the concrete surface of the driveway.

The posts are hollow, square in cross-section, with a width of about 4cm. They are embedded in concrete which stops about 1cm below the surface of the driveway.

Four of the posts are at the edges of the driveway, where they have a low wooden wall to one side, while the remaining three are in the middle.

[image: Posts]

In the right-hand photo the concrete around the base of the post is wet, as I used a power washer to clean away the dirt that had become embedded in the gap between the post and the concrete hole.

Can anyone suggest the best way for me to remove or cut them off (below the surface of the driveway)?

Very interested in any answers that include explanatory/illustrative diagrams!

Comment: [What do volts and amps imply for angle grinders?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/63111/23295) "A usage tip - if the grinder begins to bog down, ease up the pressure - the JOB gets done faster with the tool running full speed. If you apply so much pressure that the tool bogs down (labors, is not running full speed) the cutting or grinding process is slower, not faster. Let the tool work, don't force it." - be careful when it goes *pop*, binds the disk, and shoots pieces of it at you at 10k RPM. Someone else should be applying upward pressure, at a slight angle so it *maybe* doesn't bind.

Comment: *You* should probably use a sawsall and a grinding wheel, not a cutoff disk. - I await better answers, +1

Comment: Did you try pulling them out?  A jack might come in handy.

Comment: If it doesn't wobble in the slightest, I'd assume it's embedded in a footing. [How can I jack a steel post out of the ground?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/135753/how-can-i-jack-a-steel-post-out-of-the-ground)

Comment: @SteveWellens - Before I'd removed all of the horizontal timbers I did try to use my car jack, but wasn't confident about applying too much force as I was concerned about sudden movements. Either the timber breaking, the car jack giving way or a post popping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I hired someone to do the work, and was glad that I did.

In order to remove the posts they used:

- A reciprocating saw to cut the posts off
- An angle grinder to cut more of the posts off
- A powered chisel thing to get rid of some of the concrete that was inside the posts
- A hammer and lots of effort to fold the remaining parts of the posts down

Here's an image of the aftermath, for one of the posts. (the secondary circle cut in the concrete was there already, and not part of the removal works)

[image: Post remains]